# Update table set column equal to select where id matches outside of query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

This seems simple but I can't seem to wrap my head around it...
I am trying to update a table, set the columns equal to the result of a query which uses the ID column from the table which I am updating and uses a WITH() clause. I also only want to update the columns in my table where Fall_Term = 'Fall 2019'

I will provide my pseudo code and my long nasty actual code...

NOTE: My update statement works perfectly fine if I manually enter values for the ID column - PERSON_SKEY.
For example, instead of:

```
WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY
```

Doing this works:

```
WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = 12345
```

My code currently gets the error:

```
[Error] Execution (10: 27): ORA-00904: "SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS"."PERSON_SKEY": invalid identifier
```

Here is my pseudo code..

```
update Table_A 
set Column_A = 
    (select Column_B from Table_B 
    where TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.id )
where Fall_Term = 'Fall 2019';
```

Here is my actual code:

```
--UPDATE OIR TERMINAL DEGREE IN FALL 2019 SNAPSHOT
UPDATE SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS 
SET OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE = (
WITH HIGHES_DEG_VALUE AS (
    SELECT max(D.OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY) AS MAX_DEG
    FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS  V
    JOIN DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
        ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
           D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE       
    WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY) 
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN MAX_DEG = 30 
        THEN  --CHECK IF EXIST ON CROSSWALKS AND USE THAT VALUE IF IT DOES
        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE, --IF ON SUBJ CODE CROSSWALK
                         V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                         FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                         JOIN DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE 
                         INNER JOIN  SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK  S
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = S.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                            and S.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE = V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE 
                            WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY 
                         )
                THEN (SELECT DISTINCT  -- USE TERMINAL VALUE FROM SUBJ CODE
                       CASE
                             WHEN s.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN s.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END
                      FROM SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK  S
                                   INNER JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                                       ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                                          S.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                                    AND S.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE =
                                          V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                                    WHERE  V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY )                        
    
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE, --IF ON CLIC INSTRUCTORS CROSSWALK
                                V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
                                I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG
                         FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                         INNER JOIN CLIC_INSTRUCTORS_CROSSWALK C
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = C.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE 
                         AND V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE = C.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                         INNER JOIN IPEDS_REPORT_DETAILS I ON V.PIDM = I.HR_PIDM
                         WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY 
                         AND  (I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG = '396000'
                              OR I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG = '396010')
                         ) 
                THEN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN C.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN C.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
                       FROM CLIC_INSTRUCTORS_CROSSWALK C
                       INNER JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                           ON C.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                              V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                        AND C.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE =
                              V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                        WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY ))
       ELSE --USE DIM DEGREE CROSSWALK NORMALLY
            (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
            FROM DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
                 JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                     ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                        D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE
               WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY)
               ORDER BY OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY DESC
               FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
        END) --USE DIM DEGREE CROSSWALK FOR THE TERMINAL VALUE FOR THE MAX DEG THERE

    WHEN MAX_DEG != 30
    THEN
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
            FROM DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
             JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                 ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                    D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE
           WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY 
           ORDER BY OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY DESC
           FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
    ELSE NULL
END 
FROM HIGHES_DEG_VALUE ) 
WHERE SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.OIR_FALL_TERM = 'Fall 2019'
;
```

Structure of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS --(Snapshot table)
(
  OIR_ACADEMIC_RANK                    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  OIR_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG              VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  OIR_EMPLOYEE_NAME_LAST_FIRST         VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  HR_POSN_ESOC                         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  OIR_FT_PT                            VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  OIR_FACULTY_STATUS                   VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  OIR_FALL_TERM                        VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  HR_GENDER_DESCRIPTION                VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  HR_CURRENT_ID                        VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  IPEDS_RACE_ETHNICITY_DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  OIR_FACULTY_STAFF_DETAILED_ROLE      VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  OIR_MGMT_FAC_AND_INSTR_IN_FALL_TERM  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  OIR_OTHER_DEGREE_NOTES               VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  OIR_DOCTORATE                        VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  OIR_HIGHEST_DEGREE_CATEGORY          VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE                  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  OIR_PRIMARY_ROLE                     VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  HR_PIDM                              INTEGER,
  OIR_POSITION                         VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  OIR_FACULTY_SALARY                   NUMBER(13,3),
  OIR_SCHOOL                           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  OIR_TENURE_STATUS                    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  PERSON_SKEY                          INTEGER,
  CREATED_DATE                         DATE,
  MODIFIED_DATE                        DATE,
  OIR_IPEDS_OCCUPATION_CATEGORY        VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  IPEDS_RANK_DESCRIPTION               VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  OIR_POSN_SEQUENCE                    INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS --Degree Table
(
  PIDM                                           INTEGER NOT NULL,
  VPAA_FACULTY_INSTITUTION_CODE                  VARCHAR2(6 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  VPAA_FACULTY_INSTITUTION_NAME                  VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  VPAA_FACULTY_OFFICIAL_TRANSCRIPT               VARCHAR2(1 CHAR),
  VPAA_FACULTY_OFFICIAL_TRANSCRIPT_RECEIPT_DATE  DATE,
  VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE                       VARCHAR2(6 CHAR),
  VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_DESCRIPTION                VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  VPAA_FACULTY_GRADUATION_DATE                   DATE,
  VPAA_FACULTY_TERMINAL_DEGREE                   VARCHAR2(1 CHAR),
  VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE                      VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),
  VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_DESCRIPTION               VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  VPAA_FACULTY_CIPC_CODE                         VARCHAR2(6 CHAR),
  VPAA_FACULTY_ACAT_CODE                         VARCHAR2(2 CHAR),
  CREATED_DATE                                   DATE,
  MODIFIED_DATE                                  DATE,
  PERSON_SKEY                                    INTEGER,
  VPAA_FACULTY_YEARS_SINCE_GRADUATION            NUMBER,
  VPAA_CURRENT_DEGREE                            INTEGER
);

--Crosswalk tables
CREATE TABLE WHOIRMGR.SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK
(
  VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE         VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE        VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  SUBJECT_CODE_DESCRIPTION         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  PERFORMANCE_OR_THEORY            VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS       VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  CREATED_DATE                     DATE,
  MODIFIED_DATE                    DATE
);

CREATE TABLE WHOIRMGR.DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK
(
  OIR_DEGREE_LEVEL                       VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  VPAA_DEGREE_CODE                       VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  VPAA_DEGREE_DESCRIPTION                VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  CREATED_DATE                           DATE,
  MODIFIED_DATE                          DATE,
  DEGREE_LEVEL_SKEY                      INTEGER,
  OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY                   INTEGER,
  OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS             VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE              VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE_DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  PERFORMANCE_OR_THEORY                  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)
);

CREATE TABLE WHOIRMGR.CLIC_INSTRUCTORS_CROSSWALK
(
  HR_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORGN_CODE              NVARCHAR2(20),
  HR_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORGN_CODE_DESCRIPTION  NVARCHAR2(50),
  VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE                  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_DESCRIPTION           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE                 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  SUBJECT_CODE_DESCRIPTION                  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS                VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
);
```

Update: This is what ended up working!! In the subquery, I had to do a left join instead of where id matches in both tables.

```
UPDATE SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS SFC
SET OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE = (
WITH HIGHES_DEG_VALUE AS (
    SELECT max(D.OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY) AS MAX_DEG
    FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS  V
    JOIN DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
        ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
           D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE 
    left JOIN SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS S
            ON V.PERSON_SKEY = S.PERSON_sKEY) --CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN MAX_DEG = 30 
        THEN  --CHECK IF EXIST ON CROSSWALKS AND USE THAT VALUE IF IT DOES
        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE, --IF ON SUBJ CODE CROSSWALK
                         V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                         FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                         JOIN DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE 
                         INNER JOIN  SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK  S
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = S.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                            and S.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE = V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE 
                            left JOIN SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS S
                            ON V.PERSON_SKEY = S.PERSON_sKEY
                            --WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SFC.PERSON_SKEY ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
                         )
                THEN (SELECT DISTINCT  -- USE TERMINAL VALUE FROM SUBJ CODE
                       CASE
                             WHEN s.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN s.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END
                      FROM SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK  S
                                   INNER JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                                       ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                                          S.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                                    AND S.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE =
                                          V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                                          left JOIN SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS S
                                        ON V.PERSON_SKEY = S.PERSON_sKEY)
                                    --WHERE  V.PERSON_SKEY = SFC.PERSON_SKEY )----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY )                        
    
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE, --IF ON CLIC INSTRUCTORS CROSSWALK
                                V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
                                I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG
                         FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                         INNER JOIN CLIC_INSTRUCTORS_CROSSWALK C
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = C.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE 
                         AND V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE = C.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                         INNER JOIN IPEDS_REPORT_DETAILS I ON V.PIDM = I.HR_PIDM
                         --WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SFC.PERSON_SKEY ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
                         left JOIN SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS S
                            ON V.PERSON_SKEY = S.PERSON_sKEY
                         AND  (I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG = '396000'
                              OR I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG = '396010')
                         ) 
                THEN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN C.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN C.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
                       FROM CLIC_INSTRUCTORS_CROSSWALK C
                       INNER JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                           ON C.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                              V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                        AND C.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE =
                              V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                        --WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SFC.PERSON_SKEY)----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY)
                        left JOIN SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS S
                        ON V.PERSON_SKEY = S.PERSON_sKEY)
       ELSE --USE DIM DEGREE CROSSWALK NORMALLY
            (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
            FROM DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
                 JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                     ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                        D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE
               --WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SFC.PERSON_SKEY ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY)
            left JOIN SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS S
            ON V.PERSON_SKEY = S.PERSON_sKEY
               ORDER BY OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY DESC
               FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
        END) --USE DIM DEGREE CROSSWALK FOR THE TERMINAL VALUE FOR THE MAX DEG THERE

    WHEN MAX_DEG != 30
    THEN
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
            FROM DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
             JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                 ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                    D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE
             left JOIN SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS S
            ON V.PERSON_SKEY = S.PERSON_sKEY
           --WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SFC.PERSON_SKEY ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY)
           ORDER BY OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY DESC
           FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
    ELSE NULL
END 
FROM HIGHES_DEG_VALUE ) 
WHERE SFC.OIR_FALL_TERM = 'Fall 2019'
```

Comment: `Merge` statement would be much more simple and readable than update on your case

Comment: I have tried using a merge statement, but I don't understand how to write it correctly to my reflect my existing query, please see the updated question with my code :) @SayanMalakshinov

Comment: @Anderson, the final version of my answer solved your problem ? We were discussing it in a chat , so please accept and upvote the answer if it solved your issue. Really appreciated

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Your answer helped but I had to change all where clauses (V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY) to left joins instead in order for it to work

Answer (score 2):

When you use WITH with UPDATE you need to use alias for the update table. If not, it does not work.

Also, you can't invoke the UPDATED TABLE in the WITH CLAUSE, at that moment that table is unknown, that is why you get INVALID IDENTIFIER. To solve the problem you need to remove that condition and added at the end.

Try this one, but I am writing without even knowing the data model, so be aware.

```
UPDATE SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS SFC
SET OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE = (
  WITH HIGHES_DEG_VALUE AS (
    SELECT max(D.OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY) AS MAX_DEG
    FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS  V
    JOIN DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
        ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE  
    LEFT JOIN SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS S 
        ON V.PERSON_SKEY = S.PERSON_SKEY
     ) 
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN MAX_DEG = 30 
        THEN  --CHECK IF EXIST ON CROSSWALKS AND USE THAT VALUE IF IT DOES
        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE, --IF ON SUBJ CODE CROSSWALK
                         V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                         FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                         JOIN DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE 
                         INNER JOIN  SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK  S
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = S.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                            and S.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE = V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE 
                            WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
                         )
                THEN (SELECT DISTINCT  -- USE TERMINAL VALUE FROM SUBJ CODE
                       CASE
                             WHEN s.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN s.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END
                      FROM SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK  S
                                   INNER JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                                       ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                                          S.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                                    AND S.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE =
                                          V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                                    WHERE  V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY )----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY )                        
    
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE, --IF ON CLIC INSTRUCTORS CROSSWALK
                                V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
                                I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG
                         FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                         INNER JOIN CLIC_INSTRUCTORS_CROSSWALK C
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = C.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE 
                         AND V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE = C.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                         INNER JOIN IPEDS_REPORT_DETAILS I ON V.PIDM = I.HR_PIDM
                         WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
                         AND  (I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG = '396000'
                              OR I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG = '396010')
                         ) 
                THEN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN C.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN C.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
                       FROM CLIC_INSTRUCTORS_CROSSWALK C
                       INNER JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                           ON C.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                              V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                        AND C.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE =
                              V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                        WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY )----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY)
       ELSE --USE DIM DEGREE CROSSWALK NORMALLY
            (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
            FROM DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
                 JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                     ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                        D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE
               WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY)
               ORDER BY OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY DESC
               FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
        END) --USE DIM DEGREE CROSSWALK FOR THE TERMINAL VALUE FOR THE MAX DEG THERE

    WHEN MAX_DEG != 30
    THEN
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
            FROM DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
             JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                 ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                    D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE
           WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY)
           ORDER BY OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY DESC
           FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
    ELSE NULL
END 
FROM HIGHES_DEG_VALUE
) WHERE SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.OIR_FALL_TERM = 'Fall 2019' ;
```

Comment: I have made that change, however now I get the error: [Error] Execution (10: 27): ORA-00904: "SFC"."PERSON_SKEY": invalid identifier

Comment: can you provide the structure of the tables ??

Comment: You can't invoke the parent updated table in the with, it is not part of it. You need to join the table. I will edit the answer

Comment: I post a new version. I think if you move the condition to the last part of the statement, it might work. the WITH is an inline view, it can only resolve the tables inside the WITH clause

Comment: Thanks I will try that, I just posted the structure of the tables

Comment: I just realized it wont work. the field is not in the with clause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218933/discussion-between-roberto-hernandez-and-anderson).

Answer (score 0):

A `MERGE` will work best in this situation.

The idea of a `MERGE` is to take data from a source table/query (specified in the `USING` part of the `MERGE` statement) and merge it into a destination table (specified in the `MERGE INTO` part of the `MERGE` statement).

Which row from the source dataset targets which row in the destination table is specified by on the merge condition (the condition after `ON` in the `MERGE` statement).

Now that you have set up the source and destination datasets and specified how to do the merging, you have to specify what happens when the merging is done. Your row from the source dataset may find a target in the destination table or may not. If it does you specify what should happen in the `WHEN MATCHED` clause. If it doesn't find a target you specify what shoudl happen in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause.

Keeping these in mind, your `MERGE` becomes

```
MERGE INTO snp_faculty_census sfc -- DESTINATION table
USING (SELECT v.person_skey,
              MAX (d.oir_degree_hierarchy) AS max_deg
       FROM vpaa_ppaggenl_fis v
            JOIN dim_degree_crosswalk d
                ON v.vpaa_faculty_degree_code = d.vpaa_degree_code) md -- SOURCE DATASET
ON (sfc.person_skey = md.person_skey) -- MERGEing condition
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET sfc.oir_terminal_degree = md.max_deg; -- WHAT HAPPENS WHEN MEGRED
```

That's all, in my understanding, is what you need to do.
You can add a group by in your source dataset to prevent the same row from being merged again and again but it should work without that nevertheless.