# How to update a table where values in table oracle using loop or cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, updates, with-statement

This is based off another one of my questions.. see [Update table set column equal to select where id matches outside of query in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63180175/10054842)

Is it possible to use a LOOP or cursor to update my table SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS for which the PERSON_SKEY VALUES match IN SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS AND VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS  ?

I ask this because I have an update statement that works perfectly fine when I explicitly define the ID column (Person_Skey)
For example:

```
WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = 12345
```

However, if I use a where clause which gets the value from another table

```
WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS.PERSON_SKEY
```

The update statement does not update the columns correctly (I think it uses the wrong value for MAX(OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY))

Here is my code where I wish to loop with the different person_skey values in SNP_FACULTY_CENSUS:

```
WITH HIGHES_DEG_VALUE AS (
    SELECT max(D.OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY) AS MAX_DEG
    FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS  V
    JOIN DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
        ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
           D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE       
    WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = 189444) --CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN MAX_DEG = 30 
        THEN  --CHECK IF EXIST ON CROSSWALKS AND USE THAT VALUE IF IT DOES
        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE, --IF ON SUBJ CODE CROSSWALK
                         V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                         FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                         JOIN DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE 
                         INNER JOIN  SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK  S
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = S.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                            and S.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE = V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE 
                            WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY =189444 ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
                         )
                THEN (SELECT DISTINCT  -- USE TERMINAL VALUE FROM SUBJ CODE
                       CASE
                             WHEN s.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN s.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END
                      FROM SUBJ_CODE_CROSSWALK  S
                                   INNER JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                                       ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                                          S.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                                    AND S.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE =
                                          V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                                    WHERE  V.PERSON_SKEY = 189444 )----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY )                        
    
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE, --IF ON CLIC INSTRUCTORS CROSSWALK
                                V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE,
                                I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG
                         FROM VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                         INNER JOIN CLIC_INSTRUCTORS_CROSSWALK C
                         ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = C.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE 
                         AND V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE = C.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                         INNER JOIN IPEDS_REPORT_DETAILS I ON V.PIDM = I.HR_PIDM
                         WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = 189444 ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
                         AND  (I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG = '396000'
                              OR I.OIR_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_HOME_ORG = '396010')
                         ) 
                THEN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN C.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN C.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
                       FROM CLIC_INSTRUCTORS_CROSSWALK C
                       INNER JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                           ON C.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                              V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE
                        AND C.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE =
                              V.VPAA_FACULTY_SUBJECT_CODE
                        WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = 189444 )----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY)
       ELSE --USE DIM DEGREE CROSSWALK NORMALLY
            (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
            FROM DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
                 JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                     ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                        D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE
               WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = 189444 ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY)
               ORDER BY OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY DESC
               FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
        END) --USE DIM DEGREE CROSSWALK FOR THE TERMINAL VALUE FOR THE MAX DEG THERE

    WHEN MAX_DEG != 30
    THEN
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CASE
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'Yes'
                             WHEN D.OIR_TERMINAL_DEGREE_STATUS =
                                  'Not terminal'
                             THEN
                                 'No'
                             ELSE
                                 'Unknown'
                        END  
            FROM DIM_DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
             JOIN VPAA_PPAGGENL_FIS V
                 ON V.VPAA_FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE =
                    D.VPAA_DEGREE_CODE
           WHERE V.PERSON_SKEY = 189444 ----CHANGE TO  = SRC.PERSON_SKEY)
           ORDER BY OIR_DEGREE_HIERARCHY DESC
           FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
    ELSE NULL
END 
FROM HIGHES_DEG_VALUE
```

Comment: I've explained how to use a `MERGE` in your original question.

Comment: there seems to be something fundamentally wrong in this merge, which is that you are selecting a PERSON_KEY from the block H, however such a column isnt in the SELECT clause. im puzzled how the query worked